# Complete $1$- and $2$-types without parameters of $(\Bbb{R},0, +)$ and $(\Bbb{R}, 0,+, <)$

Tags: model-theory

Here is an exercise in model theory.

1. The theory of $(\Bbb{R}, 0, +)$ has exactly two $1$-types but $\aleph_0$ many $2$-types.
2. The theory of $(\Bbb{R}, 0, +, <)$ has exactly three $1$-types but $2^{\aleph_0}$ many $2$-types.

For 1, two $1$-types are $x+0=x$ and $x+(-x)=0$. For $2$-types, I think one is $x+y=y+x$, but I am not sure how to get $\aleph_0$ many $2$-types.

For 2, three $1$-types are $x+0=x$, $x+(-x)=0$ and $x>0\lor x=0\lor -x>0$. But I am not sure how to get $2^{\aleph_0}$ many $2$-types.

Note that a type in a theory $T$ is a maximal consistent set $Γ(x_1,⋯,x_{n})$ of formulas in the variables $x_1,⋯,x_{n}$.

Comment: Check the maximality. I ll first comment only on $(\mathbb {R},+,0)$. The first type is (generated by) $x=0$ which is clearly maximal, but the second one $x=x$ clearly is not... as for 2-types, again $x+y=y+x$ is true for all $x,y$, hence it doesn't give you a maximal type. Hint: $(x= y)\land(x\neq 0)$ gives you a maximal type, as well as $(x=y+y) \land (x\neq 0)$... can you see where this goes? You happend to have made similar mistakes also with the order enriched structure. So you may want to check that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever i say type, I mean complete type without parameters (as this is how you are intending them).

**Hints**

Reminder I: if $\mathcal{L}$ is a first order signature, $M$ is a $\mathcal{L}$-structure and $\overline{m} \in M^n$ is a $n$-tuple in $M$, then the set of $\varphi(\overline{x})$ such that $M \models \varphi(\overline{m})$ is a type, it is referred to as the *type of $\overline{m}$*.

Reminder II:  and $(r_0, \ldots, r_{n-1})$ and $(s_0, \ldots, s_{n-1})$ are two $n$-tuples in a $\mathcal{L}$-structure $M$ that are are conjugated by a $\mathcal{L}$-automorphism of $M$, then they have the same type.

Ingredient I: if $r \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, then $x\mapsto rx$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}, 0, +)$; if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is any $\mathbb{Q}$-linear bijection, then it is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}, 0, +)$.

Ingredient II: if $r \in (0, \infty)$ then $x \mapsto rx$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}, 0, +, <)$.

**Solutions**

$1$-types of $(\mathbb{R}, +, 0)$

The set of consequences of $x\neq 0$ is a $1$-type: it is maximal as it can alternatively be construed as the type of a fixed element $r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. The other $1$-type is $x=0$ (clearly maximal). These are the only types as if you $\Phi(x)$ is a type, then either $(x=0) \in \Phi(x)$ or $(x\neq 0) \in \Phi(x)$.

$2$-types of $(\mathbb{R}, +, 0)$

Using Ingredient I you can see that all pairs $(r,s) \in \{0\} \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus 0)$ have the same type generated by $\varphi_{0,1}(x,y)=(x=0 \land y \neq 0)$. Simiarly you can deduce that $\varphi_{1,0}(x,y)=(x\neq 0 \land y=0)$ and $\varphi_{0,0}(x, y)= (x=0 \land y=0)$ also generate complete types.

Given $q =\frac{m}{n} = \mathbb{Q}\setminus 0$ all $(r,s) \in (\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})^2$ such that $r/s=q$ all have the same type generated by $\varphi_q(x,y)= (nx = my \land x \neq 0)$. Finally note that all the pairs $(r,s) \in (\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})^2$ not standing in a rational ratio all belong to the same type because of the last part of Ingredient I. Their type is not principal; it is generated by the set of formulae $\Phi(x,y)=\{ (mx \neq ny): m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

These are all the $2$-types of $(\mathbb{R}, +, 0)$. Indeed let $\Psi(x,y)$ be any comlete type: either you have that one among $\varphi_{0,1}, \varphi_{0,0}, \varphi_{1,0}, \varphi_q$ ($q$ varying in $\mathbb{Q}$) belongs to $\Psi(x,y)$ and in such a case $\Psi$ is the types spanned by that formula, or $\Psi$ contains $\lnot\varphi_{0,1}, \lnot\varphi_{0,0}, \lnot\varphi_{1,0}, \lnot\varphi_q$ for every $q \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ and in such a case $\Psi(x,y)=\Phi(x,y)$.

$1$-types of $(\mathbb{R}, 0, +, <)$

You are correct on pointing out the types are the three generated by the formulae $(x=0)$, $(x>0)$ and $(x<0)$ respectively. You can prove these generate complete types using Ingredient II. To prove these are the only ones proceed similarly to what you did above.

$2$-types of $(\mathbb{R}, 0, +, <)$

You don't need to list all of them: you know there are at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ types because you are considering a countable language. Just note that if you have $(r,s)\in (0, \infty )^2$ and $(r',s')\in (0, \infty )^2$ such that $r/s < r'/s'$ then they have different types: you can find $q=\frac{m}{n}\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $r/s< q<r'/s'$, then $(r,s)$ satisfies $\varphi_{q}^{<}(x,y)= (nx<my)$ whereas $(r',s')$ does not.

Comment: @hermes It follows that for any two real numbers $r,s>0$, if $r\neq s$, then $(r,1)$ and $(s,1)$ have different types. Since there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ positive real numbers, there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ types.

Comment: There is no need to consider $(r,s)∈(0,∞)^2$. For any reals $x<y<z, (x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ specify two different 2-types because there’s a $r$ that $y<r<z$ and $(x,z)$ is satisfied while $(x,y)$ is not. So there are total $\aleph_1$ 2-types.

Comment: @hermes The number of 2-types is  $2^{\aleph_0}$, which is not equal to $\aleph_1$, unless the continuum hypothesis is true.

Comment: From my comment above, there is also $\aleph_1$ many types.